# Microsoft Graph Subscriptions Post Async Issue

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-sdks

Hi everyone I am having problems adding a new notification URL to open graph.

`_client` is a `GraphServiceClient` and is set up correctly, it is correctly making other requests elsewhere in the app.

Below is my c# code (Doesnt work)

```
public async Task<Subscription> SubscribeToEmailNotificationsAsync(string userId, string notificationUrl)
    {
        var subscription = new Subscription
        {
            ChangeType = "created",
            NotificationUrl = notificationUrl,
            Resource = $"users/{userId}/mailFolders('inbox')/messages",
            ExpirationDateTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(2),
            ClientState = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            LatestSupportedTlsVersion = "v1_2",
        };

        return await _client.Subscriptions.PostAsync(subscription);
    }
```

Just to confirm the below code sample works as expected:

```
public async Task<User> GetUserByEmailAsync(string email)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
            throw new ArgumentException("Mail cannot be null or empty.", nameof(email));

        var users = await _client.Users.GetAsync((config) =>
        {
            config.QueryParameters.Select = new[] { "displayName", "id", "mail" };
            config.QueryParameters.Filter = $"mail eq '{email}'";
            config.QueryParameters.Top = 1;
        });

        if(users?.Value == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Unexpected null response from the Graph API.");

        return users.Value.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

I have made the exact same request in postman with the same values and it works fine. I have also double checked the token is valid in the code.

When using charles proxy software I can see the request fails with no request body. Has anyone done something similar? Would appreciate any tips / advice.

Comment: If Postman works and your code doesn't, capture them both in Fiddler and then compare.

Comment: it just shows as a failed request with no body in Charles Proxy. I have also looked at subscription object and make sure the values are exactly correct. Have tried hardcoding in too. Cant seem to find any examples of this other than microsofts example so wondering if its a bug with sdk.

Comment: It's impossible for us to help with this since there is nothing wrong with the code you show here. In fact, it's almost identical to the [one in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#tabpanel_1_csharp). We need more details about why it failed.

Comment: Yes I can see its identical in the docks which is frustrating, is anyone else able to make it work locally? I will send more of code in question. I have hard coded in exact values I have in postman into the object and still receive an error. Getting generic error which is no help. What can you recommend to further debug this? @DavidG

Comment: Add `try-catch` around `return await _client.Subscriptions.PostAsync(subscription);` and if the exception is `ODataError`, then share `ODataError.Error.Message` and `ODataError.Error.Code` with us. Maybe try whether the code works for `Resource = $"me/mailFolders('inbox')/messages"`

Comment: In your code we can't see the connection between your controller action and the notification url. When you try to POST a new subscription, MS tries to call this URL with an empty body and the query parameter _validationToken_. You have to answer this call with 200 and the text within the validation token as response body. Otherwise your subscription won't be registered (and your POST call fails).

Comment: If this would succeed, then MS would call this webhook, but with a _ChangeNotification_ as body. Where do you process this notification in your code?

Comment: @Oliver it doesnt get this far as the original request fails

Comment: I have got it working using httpClient but not with SDK. Anyone able to reproduce issue?

Comment: If you got it to work with a HttpClient, could you update your question and add your working code, so we can check it? And just to mention it again: When you send your POST subscription, Microsoft immediately calls the notificationUrl and expects to get back a 200 and the given validation token. Otherwise your POST call to add the subscriptions fails with an error.